# How to get html of cloned element

Tags: jquery, clone

I have an input element like: `<input class="input-m" name="formelement[]" type="text">`

I want to clone it and store cloned html to a variable:

```
var txt=jQuery("input[name="+n+"[]]:first").clone().html();
```

this returns an empty string.

How can I get the html content from `.clone()`?

Comment: Are you sure the selector works? 
try jQuery("input[name="+n+"[]]:first").length to check it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
var txt=jQuery("input[name="+n+"[]]:first").clone().wrap("<div />").parent().html();
```

Comment: How I can set value in cloned field using above syntax? I am trying different ways but not getting

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the outer HTML instead of innerHTML:

```
var text = $('<div>').append(jQuery("input[name="+n+"[]]:first").clone()).html();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.html()` returns the html inside the element. I am guessing you have something like `<input name="..."/>` which has no inner html.

You should probably rely on something like [outerHtml](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/) plugin.