# How to clone input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to clone input field, but all I can do is to grab the value.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcy93hz5/1/)

When I try to do `$('#input').html()` i got and empty string.

I know that the answer is somewhere  on the surface, but I can't find it. Please help.

**EDIT**
 I DO NOT NEED a value. I said - i can do it. I need to CLONE the input as HTML. What here is not understandable?

**EDIT 2**
I tried to clone an element and get html with this:

```
$('#text').clone().html()
```

but it returns an empty value too. Although if I try to get a val:

```
$('#text').clone().val()
```

It returns a value normally

Comment: It's still not clear what you need. What are you doing with the cloned HTML? Why can't you just use `.clone()` to clone the element?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Be polite man we are not obligated to help you. If you can't precise your problem then fault is by your side not ours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get html of cloned element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821591/how-to-get-html-of-cloned-element)

Comment: Sorry me for being rude. I do not like when people's only reaction to vote down the question after they've read it poorly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
$('#input-text').html($('#test').clone().removeAttr('value'));
```

Comment: thank you a lot. I like your answer more than I've checked as right one, because it doesn't make any workarounds like "wrap('<div />')".

Answer (score 4):

As answered on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)... You can use Javascript to get the outerHTML.

```
var inputHTML = $('#input')[0].outerHTML;
```

Then you can use that variable wherever you need to on the page!

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** You can do this purely using jQuery, again, an answer on the above linked question...

```
$.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $(this).clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
};

var inputHTML = $("#input").outerHTML());
```

Comment: it is closer to the what I need, but how to do it in jQuery? Since it is easier to change attributes and values using jQuery

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is that, what I needed. Since my question caused violent reaction, I couldn't find the answer by @rnevius. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries @eatmypants!

Answer (score 4):

I think that's what you're trying to do :

```
<input id='test' value='10201' />
<p id="input-text"> Hello </p>
```

Then in jQuery :

```
var inputField = $('#test').clone();
$('#input-text').html(inputField);
```

Comment: clone() returns and object. How to convert it to pure HTML string?

Comment: If you want its html it will be `var inputFieldHtml = inputField[0]`

Answer (score 2):

The method your are looking for is **clone()**

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.clone()` method to the specific DOM element will extract the HTML(everything about it gets duplicated, raw) inherently.

```js
$("#test").clone().appendTo("#input-text").removeAttr('value');
$("input:eq(1)").attr("id", "test_02");
```

```css
input {
  margin-left: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
  width: 3.05em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='test' value='10201' />
<p id="input-text">Hello</p>
```

The `.attr()` method was added only to raise awareness of the one pitfall of utilizing the `.clone()` method - that being, it duplicates the `id` of the DOM element which is not best practice or even allowed in standard HTML programming. The best pratice in this case, would probably be to create a unique `class` that you know, will only deal with that specific DOM element so it can be duplicated as you like.

**Additional Resources**
» [Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/mcy93hz5/6/)
» [clone() API](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)
» [appendTo() API](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)
» [Class VS ID](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)